# How to calculate distance between two points in walking direction mode?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, distance

Similarly to this function that calculates distance between two points in **driving** direction mode:

```
function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
  return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
}
```

how to calculate distance between two points in **walking** direction mode?

Answer (score 1):

The calculation method using the direction service is the same for driving, walking, cycling. Here an basic example:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    path =  result.routes[0].overview_path;
    var sumKM = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        sumKM += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;  //legs = Abschnitte from point to point
    }
    sumKM = sumKM / 1000;
    //console.log("Route calculated, write the route")
    //writeRoute(path, sumKM, index)
} else if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
    alert("Could not find a route between these points");
} else {
    alert("Directions request failed! Reset Marker!");
}
});
```